# Evaluate a Dilogarithmic integral $\int_0^1 \ln(x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I believe a closed form for this integral exists since WFA is able to compute the [antiderivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%20ln%28x%29Li%282%2Cx%29). It does not come out with a closed form when I give it bounds on the integral for some reason though. This integral is tricky. I tried Feynman's Trick by paramterising with
$$I(a)=\int_0^1 \ln(ax)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)dx$$

however, $a=0$ does not give a value so this cannot be used. It would be very useful though since after differentiating we get $\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{ax}$ as the integrand which is just $\operatorname{Li}_3(x) a^{-1}$ but of course this is not possible because of the $a=0$ problem. Are there any other ways to approach this? I think integration by parts may work but I'm not sure how to deal with the integrals that result from it.

Comment: What does WFA give for the antiderivative? The integrand is unbounded – are you sure the integral converges?

Comment: It converges since I get a numeric value from WFA

Comment: @AnikPatel WFA is not perfect, and I've definitely had it give numerical values for divergent integrals before.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Integrate by parts

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \ln x\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\ dx
&= \int_0^1 \operatorname{Li}_2(x)\ d[x(\ln x-1)]\\
&=-\text{Li}_2(1) +\int_0^1 (\ln x-1)\ln(1-x)dx\\
&=-\frac{\pi^2}6 +\left(3-\frac{\pi^2}6 \right)=3-\frac{\pi^2}3
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

Using the series expansion of the dilogarithm:

$$\begin{align*}
& \int_0^1 \ln(x) \operatorname{Li}_2(x) \, dx \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2} \int_0^1 x^n \ln(x) \, dx \\
&= -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2(n+1)^2} \\
&= 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right) - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{(n+1)^2} \\
&= 2 - \frac{\pi^2}6 - \left(\frac{\pi^2}6-1\right) = \boxed{3-\frac{\pi^2}3}
\end{align*}$$